# linear programming slater condition

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am wondering if anyone could help to come up with a such example:

```
for some LP (or SPD), slater condition holds for primal, and primal problem has optimal objective value but not attainable.
```

Since slater condition holds, I can only know that primal opt obj = dual opt obj, and dual opt obj is attainable. But I can neither prove that primal opt obj is attainable nor unattainable. My guess is not always attainable. Appreciate if someone can give me an example/counterexample.

Comment: This should be tagged convex-optimization, not linear-programming. Because with a linear program, a finite primal optimal value is always attained.

Comment: Thanks. But even for LP case, assuming that it has a finite optimal value, I am still having trouble in proving that is attainable. My thought was to prove that at least one extreme point of the feasible set achieves the optimal obj value, and since the number of extreme points of the feasible set is finite, the result follows. But I have some difficulty in prove the claim that at least one extreme point achieves the optimal value...